# Visual Studio debugging and disposed objects

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

Is there a way to keep track of undisposed objects while debugging?  For example after breakpoint is hit, I'd look to view what developers have forgotten to clean up.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  It's a pity that more manual work is required for this.

Answer (score 5):

Not directly.

However, you can add finalizers to your Disposable classes, and have the finalizers call a method attributed with `[Conditional("DEBUG"]` that logs/throws/notifies you when they are hit.  This allows you to track when a Dispose() method was not called on an object at debug time, but at deployment, will just get finalized as normal.

Answer (score 2):

There is no good way to do this.  Although I agree it would be really nice, Visual Studio lacks any debugging features for keeping track of `IDisposable` values which are not yet disposed.

In the past when I've desired this type of scenario and didn't want to use WinDbg + SOS I used a form of manual tracking.  Essentially it looked like this

```
static class Util {
  private static List<WeakReference> _list = new List<WeakReference>();

  public static IEnumerable<IDisposable> Active { 
    get { return _list
            .Select(x => x.Target)
            .Where(x => x != null)
            .Cast<IDisposable>(); }
  }

  [Conditional("DEBUG")]
  public static void Track(IDisposable value) {
    _list.Add(new WeakReference(value)); 
    if (_list.Count % 100 == 0)) {
      _list.RemoveAll(x => x.Target == null);
    }
  }
}
```

Now I can just add calls to `Util.Track` in my `IDisposable` object constructor and then access the information at runtime